# Cant Automate Key Pressing in JavaScript, or JQuery for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a bot (a bot is pretty much a program that does something by its self) for a web game called 2048, but I can not automate the Key Pressing for my Chrome Extension. it is all set up, and it is working JQuery, but even though I found other people asking this, it still doesn't work! does anyone know why?

This is the code for the JS file in a snippet It is only a JS file that I am showing you, cause that is the main script for the chrome extension (other than the manifest.js). so don't expect it to work! :

```js
//2048 Bot By BukkitmanMC

//Before We begin, we Need to Modify the Document Page Before we can Start!

document.getElementsByClassName("restart-button")[0].innerHTML = "Start Bot"
var startedBot = false


function Bot() {
    //Initialising Brain

    var Game = {
        KeyCode: { //These Are the WASD Keys cause with JQuery, I don't think you can use the arrow Keys
            Up: 119,
            Down: 115,
            Left: 97,
            Right: 100,
        },
        Map: [[0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0]
        ]
    };
    
    //This is Where the Thinking Starts
    var e = $.Event('keypress');
    e.keyCode = Game.KeyCode.Up; // Character 'W'
    $("body").trigger(e);
    console.log("Up Key Pressed")

    setTimeout(Bot, 500)
};

document.getElementsByClassName('restart-button')[0].onclick = function () {
    console.log("Bot Has Started Playing! Now you Just Need to Watch!")
    Bot()
};
```

If you figured it out and you posted it already, thank you!

Comment: To answer your question requires information which is not included in your question. We would have to investigate the code for the unspecified website to see what is needed to accept a `keypress` event, Such code is required to be in the question. You would need to make an investigation of their code to see which element(s) the event needs to target. You will also need to see if they are checking to see if the event [`isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted)

Comment: Mayken, I do not understand what you mean. Can you explain it in simpler words for me? I actually don't understand it.

Comment: To solve your problem we need the code for the website it is to work with. The website will be expecting one, or more, events on specific elements. Without that information we **can't** help you beyond hot-to generically send an event. In addition, there is a property of events, `isTrusted`, which is specifically intended to allow the event listener to distinguish between events *actually* generated by the user and events generated by scripts. The web page may, or may not, check that property (need code). I have not seen anything indicating Chrome extensions can send "trusted" events.

Comment: If the website is checking `isTrusted`, then you will probably have to use Firefox and an extension type other than WebExtensions, as WebExtensions do not have the capability to send `isTrusted=true` events. If the website is attempting to prevent users from installing scripts to control things, then one of the first, and easy, things they should do is ignore any events that don't have `isTrusted=true`.

Comment: still don't get it...

Answer (score 1):

I created a quick fiddle where you can see that using Jquery works :

```
$(function(){
    var Game = {
        KeyCode: { 
            Up: 119,
            Down: 115,
            Left: 97,
            Right: 100,
        },
        Map: [[0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0]
        ]
    };
    $("body").keypress(function(e)
    {
        $("#log").append("key pressed : " + e.which + "<br>")
    });
    function repeat(){
      var e = $.Event('keypress');
      e.keyCode = Game.KeyCode.Up;
      e.which = Game.KeyCode.Up;
      $("body").trigger(e);
    }

    setInterval(repeat,500);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yjL2aL9y/

I made few changes though :

- Encapsulate code in $(function(){})
- Set the "which" property on the Event

Depending how the keyboard listener is made in the game, it is possible that the listener is on a specific DOM element and not "body" and also that it uses "stopPropagation" to prevent bubbling.

Comment: that is more helpful, but I want the whole function to repeat its self. do you know how to fix that?

Comment: It is already repeating with setInterval(repeat,500). You can see on the jsfiddle the log keeps happening

Comment: that is not what I mean. I meant to say that I want the whole function with the Game variable to completely repeat its self

Comment: I also forgot to mention, the code still doesn't do it on the website